# How to test params based redirection in grails

Tags: grails, spock

For example ;

this my controller code , but i don't no  how to write test cases for this in grails using Spock.

```
if(params.create){ 
    redirect(action: "create", controller: "premiumFeature") 
}else if(params.taxslab){ 
    redirect(action: "create", controller: "taxSlab") 
}
```

In this `create` and `taxSlab` is buttons name

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can test redirections based on `redirectedUrl` property of response. Something like this:

```
@TestFor(MyController)
class MyControllerSpec extends Specification {

    void "your test"() {
        when: 
        def request = controller.request
        request.addParameter("create", "paramvalue")

        and: 
        controller.yourAction()

        then: 
        response.redirectedUrl == "/premiumFeature/create"
    }
}
```